# Package Restore drops pending zero, installing package does not

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

We have an internal NuGet feed, one of the packages is `EPPlus.3.1.3.0.nupkg`. Inside the package, `EPPlus.nuspec` file contains `<version>3.1.3.0</version>` and the file under `package\services\metadata\core-properties\`contains `<version>3.1.3.0</version>`.

In the package browser, it's listed as *Version: 3.1.3.0*. When installing this package, it is placed under `packages\EPPlus.3.1.3.0`. The `.csproj` file contains `<HintPath>..\packages\EPPlus.3.1.3.0\lib\net20\EPPlus.dll</HintPath>`.

When restoring the package, it's instead restored under `packages\EPPlus.3.1.3`. This causes the build to fail. Removing and reinstalling the package makes the build work again.

What's causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official NuGet repository also hosts this package, but it uses version 3.1.3 instead of 3.1.3.0

Package restore checks all your feeds in a certain order, which can be set under *Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources* by clicking arrow buttons. If the official repository is listed above your internal feed, it will instead try to restore the package from there.

So while theoretically both packages should hold the same version, the project will indeed fail to build. I've raised a bug report [here](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4307).